# Integer to English challenge

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, numbers-to-words

I have a challenge, which is to create a JavaScript function that turns a given number into the string representation. For example:

`console.log(inToEnglish(15))` should print `fifteen`

`console.log(inToEnglish(101))` should print `one hundred one`

and so on...

This challenge covers Non-Negative, greater than zero Integer numbers.

I have accomplished this objective with the following code:

```
var b4Twenty = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
    "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen",
    "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
];

var b4Hundred = ["twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy",
    "eighty", "ninety"
];

function intToEnglish(n) {
    return translator(n).trim();
}

function translator(n) {
    if( n == 0)
        return "";   
    else if (n <= 19)
        return b4Twenty[n - 1] + " ";
    else if (n <= 99)
        return b4Hundred[Math.floor(n / 10 - 2)] + " " + translator(n % 10);
    else if (n <= 199)
        return "one hundred " + translator(n % 100);
    else if (n <= 999)
        return translator(Math.floor(n / 100)) + "hundred " + translator(n % 100);
    else if (n <= 1999)
        return "one thousand " + translator(n % 1000);
    else if (n <= 999999)
        return translator(Math.floor(n / 1000)) + "thousand " + translator(n % 1000);
    else if (n <= 1999999)
        return "one million " + translator(n % 1000000);
    else if (n <= 999999999)
        return translator(Math.floor(n / 1000000)) + "million " + translator(n % 1000000);
    else if (n <= 1999999999)
        return "one billion " + translator(n % 1000000000);
    else if (n <= 999999999999)
        return translator(Math.floor(n / 1000000000)) + "billion " + translator(n % 1000000000);
    else if (n <= 1999999999999)
        return "one trillion " + translator(n % 1000000000000);
    else if(n <= 999999999999999)
        return translator(Math.floor(n / 1000000000000)) + "trillion " + translator(n % 1000000000000);
    else if (n <= 1999999999999999)
        return "one quadrillion " + translator(n % 1000000000);
    else
        return translator(Math.floor(n / 1000000000000000)) + "quadrillion " + translator(n % 1000000000000000);
}
```

This is my recursive function to achieve the given goal. It works, and it takes 65ms to complete the battery of 50 tests.

However, I have some concerns regarding its performance:

- Given that recursive functions are usually slower than iterative ones, is there a way to make this iterative?
- Should I use a `switch` case, or is my `if` statement OK?
- I keep using `Math.floor` to round the numbers and find the indexes. Perhaps there is a better solution out there without using this technique?
- I have to wrap the translator function (who does all the work) into another function because I need to `trim` the final result of extra spaces. Is there a way I can avoid this?

I am open to suggestions on how to improve this. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/90349/10582 .

Comment: Not worthy of a full answer, but use proper words like`before` and not `b4`. Also I think that *before* isn't the best choice for what you want to express. *Below* is a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! I came up with a premature function in my spare time. There are many TODOs should be done, but I think that its a good start.

First, instead of splitting logic into array, I would rather use an mapping object (dictionary).

```
const mapNumberToString = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eight",
    9: "nine",
    10: "ten",
    11: "eleven",
    12: "twelve",
    13: "thirteen",
    14: "fourteen",
    15: "fifteen",
    16: "sixteen",
    17: "seventeen",
    18: "eighteen",
    19: "nineteen",
    20: "twenty",
    30: "thirty",
    40: "forty",
    50: "fifty",
    60: "sixty",
    70: "seventy",
    80: "eighty",
    90: "ninety",
    100: "hundred",
    1000: "thousand",
    1000000: "million",
    1000000000: "billion",
    1000000000000: "trillion",
    1000000000000000: "quadrillion"
};
```

Then, my function goes like this...

```
const intToEnglish = (n) => {
    const arr = n.toString().split('').map(s => +s);
    let eng = "0";

    // under 20
    if (n <= 20 && n > 0) {
        eng = mapNumberToString[n];
    }
    // 21 ~ 99
    else if (arr.length < 3) {
        eng = [
            mapNumberToString[arr[0]*10],
            mapNumberToString[arr[1]]
        ].join(' ');
    }
    // 100 ~ 999
    else if (arr.length < 4) {
        eng = [
            mapNumberToString[arr[0]],
            mapNumberToString[100],
            intToEnglish(n % 100)
        ].join(' ');
    }
    // above 1000
    else {
        const exp = Math.pow(1000, Math.floor( (arr.length - 1) / 3));
        eng = [
            intToEnglish(Math.floor(n / exp)),
            mapNumberToString[exp],
            intToEnglish(n % exp)
        ].join(' ');
    }

    return eng.trim();
};
```

Taking advantages of `array` and recursive function, and also javascript weird `undefined` to make this magic happen.

```
1: one
5: five
10: ten
15: fifteen
20: twenty
25: twenty five
100: one hundred
105: one hundred five
115: one hundred fifteen
120: one hundred twenty
212: two hundred twelve
232: two hundred thirty two
999: nine hundred ninety nine
1000: one thousand
1234: one thousand two hundred thirty four
12345: twelve thousand three hundred forty five
123456: one hundred twenty three thousand four hundred fifty six
234100: two hundred thirty four thousand one hundred
1032001: one million thirty two thousand one
5000021: five million twenty one
810238903242: eight hundred ten billion two hundred thirty eight million nine hundred three thousand two hundred forty two
```

In this way, you can easily add up your mapping object without changing your code (quintillion, sextillion...). Plus, there are less if statement, which I think is easier to read, in my own opinion of course lol.

Again, there is so much to improve, and I currently don't have that much time :(.

Answer (score 3):

`intToEnglish(-1)` returns "undefined", which might not be what you want. Same goes for fractional values, although I guess that case could be waved... if you only support integers. Even so, you might want to add a check. At the very least, add a comment - problem descriptions are kept separate from your code right now, and that makes it non-obvious that it doesn't support such things!

Negative numbers could be supported via prepending "minus", then `translator(Math.abs(n))`.

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo in my post !
The code is for integers (as the title indicates), but I will add the other parts of the information missing. 
The code is correct, thank you for noticing ! rep++